# R vector of absolute times out of inter arrival times

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector with inter arrival times and need a vector with absolute times. The start time is known.

```
KnownData <- c(1,2,3)
StartTime <- 2
WantedResult <- c(3, 5, 8)
```

Can anybody please help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can use `Reduce` and this should also work in case of complex calculations

```
Reduce(function(x, y) x + y, KnownData, init = StartTime, accumulate = TRUE)[-1]
#[1] 3 5 8
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cumsum` :

```
StartTime + cumsum(KnownData)
#[1] 3 5 8
```